# I created a function using fopen in php if i use it as a function it doesnt work if i use it alone it does

Tags: php, jquery

Basically i created a some code that creates a file....
I can use that code and works perfectly in the IF statements in my code... now... because i have to use it twice... I decided to make it a function... but as soon as i make it a function it  doesnt work...

anyone can tell me why??
I am just calling the function inside others IF statements as 
`if (createFile()) {
 echo "it worked";
}`

```
function createFile () {
        //Creates File and populates it.
        $fOpen = fopen($dbFile, 'w');

            $fString .= "<?php\n";
            $fString .= "// Database Constants\n";
            $fString .= "define(\"DB_SERVER\", \"$server\");\n";
            $fString .= "define(\"DB_USER\", \"$username\");\n";
            $fString .= "define(\"DB_PASS\", \"$password\");\n";
            $fString .= "define(\"DB_NAME\", \"$dbname\");\n";
            $fString .= "?>";

        fwrite($fOpen, $fString);
        fclose($fOpen);
}
```

Comment: The function createFile has no return value, so that would explain why if (createFile()) { echo "it worked"; } doesn't echo anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass in the value for $dbFile to the function. Like

```
function createFile($dbFile) {
```

This is typically considered a better approach than declaring the $dbFile variable as global inside the function.

Comment: It should also return a value if OP is going to use it in a comparison.